# Supervisor Django Gunicorn Gevent Memory Usage

Tags: django, ubuntu, gevent, gunicorn, supervisord

I am running Django 1.4 sites on Ubuntu 12.04 with supervisor 3.0a8-1.1 and have run into a strange problem with gunicorn 0.17.2 and gevent 0.13.8.

Supervisor's memory usage keeps growing until the server is not responsive.

There are 5 sites with the following supervisor configs:

```
command=/app/virtualenv/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /app/virtualenv/bin/python /app/manage.py run_gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py -k gevent
directory=/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
environment=NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE='/app/newrelic.ini'
```

and the following gunicorn configs:

```
workers = 4
bind = '0.0.0.0:(Site Port Number)'
```

These are all being reverse proxied to via NGINX.

I am running these on a large EC2 instance which has 2 cores and 7.3GB of RAM which should be way more than I need.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: This could be a million things. Have you tried using a blank django project and seeing if the memory issues persist? You need to eliminate your code from the problem set first, then worry about potential bugs in either new-relic, gevent or gunicorn.

Comment: I have 2 sites one with standard Mezannine and another with standard Djando CMS. Neither of these are using newrelic. These are as standard as I can get as a blank project doesn't use enough memory to monitor reliably on request as far as I can tell. I have run these 2 projects without supervisor and memory gets cleared as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If memory is clearing correctly when you just run the projects without supervisord, that's baffling.

Supervisord is just a daemon manager. It doesn't do anything but launch and manage a process, which, in this case, is just manage.py.

The only thing I could think is that autorestart is turned on, which has been known to cause a memory leak, if supervisor is constantly restarting the process because it detects a change and errors don't get cleared out. This was [actually fixed in supervisor 3.0b1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor). Maybe update your supervisor?

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try that. autorestart is on.

Comment: Updating supervisor has indeed stopped the memory issue with Guniciorn. We also had some leaks in celery tasks which is why it has taken quite a bit of further testing to confirm this.